# Bootstrap Group buttons still showing radio buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am trying to use a btn group but the radio button is still showing is there anyway to disable it.

```
<div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Poi">
     <i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Vessel">
      <i class="fa fa-motorcycle fa-lg"></i>
   </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Intel">
       <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
   <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Location">
<i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
   </label>
</div>
```

Here is my test.

https://www.codeply.com/p/WYm7W2iprl

Also how does one make the buttons a normal button size. I still want the image just not the radio button but bare in mind this needs to be able to selected with Asp.net mvc

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I suppose you want to hide the radio button, but still want to select the Icon. If that is the case, you could try to use CSS "display:none" property to hide the Radio button, then using JQuery to checked/unchecked the radio button when click the Icons. Please refer to the following sample code (or [Link](https://codepen.io/Dillion121/pen/KKVQxze)):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".btn-group > .btn").each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).click(function () {
                $(".btn-group input[type = 'radio']:checked").prop('checked', false);
                $(this).find("input[type='radio']").prop("checked", true);

                //alert the checked radiobutton value.
                alert($(".btn-group input[type = 'radio']:checked").val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Poi" style="display:none">
        <i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Vessel" style="display:none">
        <i class="fa fa-motorcycle fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Intel" style="display:none">
        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="Selection" value="Location" style="display:none">
        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Then, the output like this:

[image]

Besides, to increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33% increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

More detail information, you could check [this link](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/).

Answer (score 1):

To hide the default radio button, just add the `hidden` attribute to `<input>`.

```
<div class="btn-group type-select pull-left top-buffer add-on" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input hidden type="radio" name="Selection" value="Poi">
        <i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input hidden type="radio" name="Selection" value="Vessel">
        <i class="fa fa-motorcycle fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input hidden type="radio" name="Selection" value="Intel">
        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input hidden type="radio" name="Selection" value="Location">
        <i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```